# Django with celery can't get result from backend

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery

My django project is cloned from Celery repo: https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/3.1/examples/django . In settings after const BROKER_URL I added

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
```

I'm trying task called 'add' from the project. Inside worker terminal result is ok but can't get it back. I call command something like this:

```
from demoapp.tasks import add
add.delay(2,2)
add.AsyncResult(a.task_id).get()
```

But don't know why I get error:

```
<ipython-input-3-5f18de09f6a1> in <module>()
----> 1 add.AsyncResult(a.task_id).get()

/home/t/py/django/celeryexample/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/result.pyc in get(self, timeout, propagate, interval, no_ack, follow_parents, EXCEPTION_STATES, PROPAGATE_STATES)
    167             interval=interval,
    168             on_interval=on_interval,
--> 169             no_ack=no_ack,
    170         )
    171         if meta:

/home/t/py/django/celeryexample/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.pyc in _is_disabled(self, *args, **kwargs)
    595     def _is_disabled(self, *args, **kwargs):
    596         raise NotImplementedError(
--> 597             'No result backend configured.  '
    598             'Please see the documentation for more information.')
    599     wait_for = get_status = get_result = get_traceback = _is_disabled

NotImplementedError: No result backend configured.  Please see the documentation for more information
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran task from ipython instead manage.py shell so that's the issue

Comment: Damn, I thought it works from a normal shell and was struggling to fix a non-existing problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install 'django_celery_results'
```

add django_celery_results in INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py(it will create one table to store result)

Set celery result as below in settings.py of your procject

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'

python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

restart worker ..Done

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because you're setting the backend to use a AMPQ compatible backing storage, which you don't have. 
Usual AMPQ storage is RabbitMQ but there are others like ActiveMQ, Apollo etc.

I recommend not to use AMPQ for persistence, unless you have a dedicated server.

You can instead use a database or redis for storing the results. For testing purposes you can use SQLite,

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'db+sqlite:///results.db'
```

From [celery docs](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#id3)

Comment: i have AMPQ server, but when I changed to sqllite config I have the same error